# There is a disjoint compact set from a closed set in a locally compact space

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to prove a statement but an easy step is missing. I believe that

> In a locally compact Hausdorff space $X$, given a point $x \in X$ and a closed
>   set $A \subset X$ such that $\{x\} \cap A = \emptyset$, there is a compact set $K$
>   with $x \in \mathring{K}$ and $K \cap A = \emptyset$

Is this true? Can you tell me why?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: $A$ is closed and $x\notin A$. What does that mean? The space is locally compact. What does that mean?

Comment: @DanielFischer I think the definition of local compactness is: "For any point there is a neighbourhood with a compact closure." So, in this case what if the only such neigbourhood is the open set $X - A$. Then its closure might intersect $A$. What am I missing?

Comment: Aha. That cannot happen. There's a theorem, that in a Hausdorff space, if a point has one compact neighbourhood, the compact neighbourhoods form a neighbourhood basis at that point. This exercise is more or less to prove that theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Let $U$ be a neighbourhood of $x$ such that $C:=\overline{U}$ is compact. If $C$ misses $A$, you are done, if not we have a compact Hausdorff space $C$ and $A \cap C$ is closed in it, and $x$ is not in it. Now apply that $C$ (as a subspace) is regular, and proceed from there.